# exit function when interrupted

Tags: c, microcontroller, interrupt

I have an interrupt function called, `interrupt_Foo() {...}` which turns on a flag when 1 second has elapsed, and a user-defined function `foo_calling() {...}` which calls another function `foo_called() {...}`. I want to stop the process in `foo_called()` when 1 second has elapsed.

The code snippet below may elaborate further my need:

```
void interrupt interrupt_foo() {
   ...
   if(1 second has elapsed) {
      flag1s = 1;
   } else {
      flag1s = 0;
   }
}

void foo_calling() {
   // need something here to stop the process of foo_called()
   ...
   (*fptr_called)(); // ptr to function which points to foo_called
   ...
}

void foo_called() {
   // or something here to stop the process of this function
   ...
   // long code
   ...
}
```

This is real time operating system so polling the 1 second flag inside foo_called() at some portion in the code is undesirable. Please help.

Comment: How else would you expect the function to stop without polling the flag?  Would you rather kill the thread instead?  That doesn't sound like the best option IMHO.

Comment: THat's my problem. Since this is intended for a microcontroller (i.e. PIC), threading may have complex implementation. If doing pre-emptive RTOS in microcontroller seems impossible, then I would resort to polling instead as a last resort.

Comment: I'm with Jeff, I think that the only way to solve this is by polling that variable. There are clever ways to poll depending on what is in foo_called(), such as using a sentinel value or something like that. The only way I see you solving this otherwise is if you're writing/editing the RTOS and you somehow alter the TCB in the signal handler, and have a clever way of managing that.

Comment: Either your RTOS or hardware should provide you an interrupt Handler (as in the answers below).  If not; you have to poll in the long code section yourself.

Comment: Are you trying to stop `foo_called` completely -- abort it's processing?  Or are you trying to suspend it while you do something else -- essentially implementing your own threading?  (My answer was assuming the first, but upon re-reading, I'm not sure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to write non-portable code, and test the heck out of it before deploying it, and if the processor supports it, there may be a solution.

When the interrupt handler is called, the return address must be stored somewhere.   If that is a location your code can query - like a fixed offset down the stack - then you can compare that address to the range occupied by your function to determine if 'foo_called is executing.    You can get the address of the function by storing a dummy address, compiling,  parsing the map file, then updating the address and recompiling.

Then, if your processor supports it, you can replace the return address with the address of the last  instruction(s) of foo_called.   (make sure you include the stack cleanup and register restoration code.).    Then exit the interrupt as normal, and the interrupt handling logic will return code to the end of your interrupted function.

If the return address is not stored in the stack, but in an unwritable register, you still may be able to force quit your function - if the executable code is in writrable memory.    Just store the instruction at the interruupt's return address, then overwrite  it with a jump instruction which jumps to the function end.    In the caller code, add a detector which restored the overwritten instruction.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that your RTOS has some kind of timer signal/interrupt that you can use to notify you when one second has passed. For instance if it is a realtime UNIX/Linux then you would set a signal handler for SIGALRM for one second. On a RT variant of Linux this signal will have more granularity and better guarantees than on a non-RT variant. But it is still a good idea to set the signal for slightly less than a second and busy-wait (loop) until you reach one second.